# Remove quotation marks when printing data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that consists of 2 columns (Main, Sub). I iterate through the data frame and print the results.

The second column, however, keeps having quotation marks, which is not ideal.

How do I remove them? I tried using `.strip("'")`, but nothing changed.

[image: head of data frame]

[image: my code]

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Please don't add your code as an image, add it as text so it's easier for us to help you.

Comment: sorry for that. thought it would have embedded the image.

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print("Main structure %s with %r and one of its subs" % (row[0], row[1].replace("'","")))

Comment: It's alright but please don't add the code in the comments afterwards, edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert dataframe object to string:

```py
row[1].str.strip("'")
```

Comment: thanks. when I add .str or .str() I get the following error. Running the code out of Jupyter. 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: Ok, that means that it's already a string. Then you can do either `.replace("'","")` or `.strip("'")` one more time.

Comment: Tried but nothing changed. Editted the code to below:
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print("Main structure " + row[0] + " with " + row[1] + " and one of its subs")
And that looks like it did the trick. not sure why